# Powershell - Delete all non mp3 files

Tags: powershell

I´m totally new to Powershell and wanted to write a script that deletes all non-mp3 files in a directory.

My solution:

```
get-childitem -Recurse | 
Where-Object {!($_.PSIsContainer)} | 
Where {$_.Extension -ne ".mp3"} | 
remove-item
```

What can be improved in this statement or could be written in another way.
Are there any problems with this statement?

Thank you.

Comment: I would go with xcud's answer but keep in mind that you can combine tests into a single Where-Object command e.g. `Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.Extension -ne '.mp3')}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use just one `Where-Object` command:

```
Get-childitem -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.Extension -ne '.mp3'} | 
    Remove-Item -whatIf
```

If you're certain that no directories have 'mp3' extension :

```
Get-childitem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne '.mp3'} | 
    Remove-Item -whatIf
```

Remove `-whatIf` to delete the files.

Comment: Describes what would happen if you executed the command without actually executing the command.