# How to judge certain type of files(suce as csv file) exist using powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, get-childitem

I need a function to delete all the csv files in a folder A, if there is csv files in folder A , then delete all the csv files(actually, I don't know the exact csv files' name in folder A); 
if there is no csv file in folder A , then do nothing.
I have searched a topic about removing mp3 files:
[Powershell - Delete all non mp3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086861/powershell-delete-all-non-mp3-files)

then I take the example out and below is the cmdlet that delete my csv files in folder A :

```
Get-childitem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.csv'} | 
Remove-Item -whatIf
```

but there is a problem , when there is no csv files in folder A , when excuting above cmd will cause error. I just don't know how to judge if csv file exists, anyone else can help? thx very much.

Comment: In your code sample you are deleting all files excluded csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `-ErrorAction` to `remove-item` to skip the error:

```
Get-childitem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne '.csv'} | 
Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: think that maybe it's the best method.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if construct to test if a condition is true before executing the deletions:

```
if(gci c:\folderA -filter *.csv){do-something}
```

If the statement between the parentheses returns false, the code between the curly braces is not executed.